# How does ltrim work in angular-filter?

Tags: angular

I'm using this angular filter: https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter.
I have problems with ltrim and rtrim.
What I want is to trim a set number of characters, not a defined portion of a string.

I've tried this (part of my code):

```
<td>{{player.remarks | truncate: 20:'...':true}}
    <span>{{player.remarks | ltrim: chars:5}}</span>
</td>
```

Is it possible to do a left or right trim based on a number of characters?

Any help welcome!

Jojoseph

Answer (score 0):

***trim*** is used only for removing the spaces on left/right side.
In Javascript, We have a method

> slice

on strings, which you can use.
'String'.slice(fromIndex, toIndex)
where toIndex can be negative coming from right side,
Ex:

```
"abcdefgh".slice(2) > cdefgh
"abcdefgh".slice(2, 4) > cd
"abcdefgh".slice(2, -2) > cdef
```

Comment: You're very right @Siddaram H! I did oversee this javascript method. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.